# Проброс портов на роутере TP-Link 940N

Tags: сеть, роутер, порты, nat, маршрутизатор

Есть 2 китайские неопознанные видеокамеры, чья ТП не отвечает. Сеть работает через бюджетный TP-Link (Если пригодится, OpenWRT на него есть).

1. Пробросил порты, на веб интерфейс камер из интернета заходит, но изображения нет. Проблема в том, что для отображения используется Flash Player, и через dev tools браузера увидел, что этот плеер использует помимо указываемого в настройках мной порта, еще и порт 1935, который я в веб интерфейсе настроить не могу.
2. Пробросил порт 1935 через Virtual Server на IP одной камеры, теперь все работает. А как быть со второй? Я не могу поставить тот же порт на другой IP, я не могу поменять этот порт в веб морде камеры.

Есть какое либо решение проблемы? Уже хотел и сохранить настройки камеры и через HEX редактор найти и поменять порт, но конфиг просто нельзя сохранить. Нет такого пункта.

Возможно ли сделать переадресацию, допустим с моего внешнего IP:123456 на внутренний IP1:1935 и IP:1234567 на внутренний IP2:1935. Стандартная прошивка такого не позволяет, поможет ли кастомная?

Comment: Я не уверен что вопрос не удалят как офтопик, поэтому пишу тут. То чего вы хотите - невозможно и на более дорогом железе с любым типом прошивки. Почитайте про NAT и разберитесь как он работает. Если нет возможности изменить порт FlashPlayer-а, то пробросить штатную веб-морду получится только от одной камеры.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял Вашу ситуацию:

- есть роутер 192.168.1.1 (внутренний ip) 198.51.100.2 (внешний ip)
- есть камера 1 192.168.1.10 с портами для проброса 80 (веб-интерфейс) 1935 (поток)
- есть камера 2 192.168.1.20 с теми же портами для проброса.

Надо работать с ними через интернет. Делаем так:

настраиваем проброс портов на роутере для первой камеры

- 198.51.100.2:180 на 192.168.1.10:80 и
- 198.51.100.2:11935 на 192.168.1.10:1935

Для второй камеры проброс

- 198.51.100.2:280 на 192.168.1.20:80 и
- 198.51.100.2:21935 на 192.168.1.20:1935

Для доступа к камере1 через интернет подключаемся 198.51.100.2:180 и 198.51.100.2:11935

для второй 198.51.100.2:280 и 198.51.100.2:21935.

Должно работать на любом роутере, где можно указать разные порты для проброса.

Comment: А теперь объясните веб-морде камеры, что ей надо лезть за видеопотоком не на 1935.

Comment: Я поэтому и написал, если правильно понял. Я 4 китайские камеры так в бесплатную ContaCam заводил и смотрел уже через неё.